# How to install magento 2 module manually facing error

Tags: magento2

I'm trying to install slider module from FTP and facing some errors. Please help [image]

Comment: please follow the system requirements http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/install-gde/system-requirements2.html

Answer (score 0):

Check the php version compatibility here : http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/install-gde/system-requirements-tech.html

Magento needs some PHP extensions. You can find it here: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/install-gde/system-requirements-tech.html

For other rediness checks please visit http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/comp-mgr/module-man/compman-readiness.html